# Find multiple Value in Array in For Loop

Tags: sql, arrays, for-loop

I have an array say `[B1, B2......B30],`

How to write a query which checks for conditions as below

IF one of the Value in array = B13, then Check if array also has B27
Then Show B13B27
Else If only B13 is there 
Then SHow B13
Else if B26 is there
THEN Show B26

My  code is (assuming all variables declared)
@BR is the array
@BC is count of records in @BR
Kindly dis-regard the functions/parameters used

---

```
FOR @i = 1 TO @BC DO

        IF (Row(@BR,@i),1) == "B13" THEN
                PRINT "B13"
        ELSEIF (Row(@BR,@i),1)  == "B26" THEN
            PRINT "B26"
        ENDIF
NEXT @i
```

---

I want to add condition for B13 and B27.
Pls advise.

Comment: Is that code supposed to be SQL? Which dbms?

Comment: It is for ExactTarget, but SQL Works just fine in that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on PHP with SQL, you can go with "in_array" PHP function like,

```
$array = array('B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B26', 'B27');

foreach($array as $value){
    if($value == 'B13' || $value == 'B27'){
        if(in_array('B13',$array) && in_array('B27',$array)){
          echo 'B13B27';
    }else if(in_array('B13',$array)){
        echo 'B13';
    }else if(in_array('B27',$array)){
        echo 'B27';
    }
}
}
```

Comment: PHP Does not work.
Pls see the FOR Loop i used. Can something be done there ?

Comment: on  what platform your usign the SQL like PHP or what

Comment: Platform is Salesforce Marketing Cloud (ExactTarget)